# How can I emit to all sockets that are NOT in a room?

Tags: socket.io

I'd like to emit a function to all the sockets that have connected but are not inside a specific room. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Im with mobile now at the train , i will try to show you more accurate code.
But consider looping to io.engine.clients you will get an array of connected sockets.

With io.nsp['/'].adapter.rooms['roomName']

You get all the socket id in a room, if you loop it you can acces to a socket like io.socket.connected[yourvarforloop].emit....

All you have to do is put it together with some for (var x in ....) help it with Object.keys( array ) some if to avoid exactly room you want to exclude and you will got it